# How can I use objects of a class in a numba jitted function without jitting the whole class?

Tags: python, design-patterns, numba

I have a class that creates an object that holds several arrays (numpy arrays) as their children. The class holds all the complex logic to build these arrays. A simple mock-up with just one attribute looks like this:

```py
class System():
    def __init__(self,backend='numpy'):
        if backend == 'numpy':
            self.D = np.ones((2,2))
        else:
            # Mock-up for other backend types
            self.D = [[1,1],[1,1]]
```

In the real code, this adds multiple attributes to the class that are determined at runtime when the class is initialized. If the backend is e.g. `'numpy'`, then all attributes will be numpy arrays. For simplicity I add here just one attribute `D`.

The purpose of this class is that the user can utilize the attributes in functions that he provides as it is very likely that they will contain a lot of loops therefore making njit speeding up the code significantly. I want now the user to be able to njit his functions. Again, a mock-up example:

```py
### User code
a = System(backend='numpy')

@nb.njit()
def user_provided_function():
    result = a.D * 2
    return result

out = user_provided_function()
print(out)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as numba will complain that the function cannot be njitted as the type of `a` is not defined / jitable. It is even clearer that this won't work if the user avoids the bad habit of a global variable and instead uses this code:

```py
### User code
@nb.njit()
def user_provided_function(a):
    result = a.D * 2
    return result

b = System(backend='numpy')
out = user_provided_function(b)
print(out)
```

My main problem is, that I cannot make a jitclass out of the class above as there are backends that are not numba-compatible. However, I like that for the class, I only have one piece of code where I can provide multiple backends and that the user can easily change backends without refactoring the whole code.

What would be a clean way to provide circumvent this problem? I like the beauty of just typing `a.D`in the user code and would like to keep an as clean as possible interface for the user.

Comment: Do you need to use global variables (in the example `a` is global object)? Why not put parameters in `user_provided_function`?

Comment: This is not possible to njit only a function of a class because the self type would be a CPython object. Also note that global variables are supposed to be (compile-time) constant in Numba AFAIK (which mean they should not change or the funciton is recompiled for every different value). Global variables are very bad anyway (both for software engineering and performance).

Comment: Yes, of course one could do avoid global variables (and probably should). This is just an example what a user might provide. However, for the actual problem I don't see how this would solve it. Indeed, I think it makes it even clearer that numba cannot deal with it. However, I adjusted the question, such that this is not obfuscating what question I intend to solve.

Comment: If you have a good idea how this could be solved by parametrizing the user_provided_function, I am very happy to do so. However, I don't want to hand over all attributes of the object ``a`` as parameters ot the ``user_provided_function``(or more precisely require the user to do so) as this will make the code very clumsy.  I basically used a class as a nice “container” of all "base arrays" that the simulation system has and that the user can use in his code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to not pass python object to numba function but instead numpy array.

Think about numba compiled functions in a way they just accept arrays and return new arrays/modifie these arrays, nothing more. That will keep your program simple:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


class System:
    def __init__(self, backend="numpy"):
        if backend == "numpy":
            self.D = np.ones((2, 2), dtype=np.float32)
        else:
            # Mock-up for other backend types
            self.D = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]


@nb.njit("float32[:, :](float32[:, :])")
def user_provided_function(a):
    return a * 2


b = System(backend="numpy")
out = user_provided_function(b.D)  # <-- don't pass whole object, just array from this object
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]]
```